# pjllib install on ubuntu

Tags: linux, software-installation

Feel like a total noob,but could someone please guide me on how to install the printer job language commands found at

[PJL-lib](https://github.com/fridayhub/security/tree/master/PJL-lib-1.3-src)

I am not quite sure how to compile this to run the pft command.  I am on ubuntu 22.04 and I am going to use this for a printer insecurity demo at school.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the PJL directory, run

```
make && make -C pft
```